# Как добавить к переменой число?

Tags: java, android

Есть переменная `total`. К ней необходимо добавить число, вводимое пользователем. Проблема в том, что пользователь будет вводить некоторые числа в это поле неоднократно. Значит, эта временная переменная должна после добавления к общему возвращаться в ноль? Прошу указать на примерах. Понимаю, почему компилятор не воспринимает `+=`, но не знаю, как исправить

```
tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewfood);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String foodstr = intent.getStringExtra("gift");

    Integer foodint = Integer.valueOf(foodstr);
    int foodtotalint;
    foodtotalint += foodint
    String foodtotalstr = String.valueOf(foodtotalint);
    tvView.setText(foodtotalstr);
```

Необходимо добавить к `foodtotalint`. Пользователь вводит `foodint`.

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос. У вас не получается прибавить число или вы не можете взять число из текстового формата? в последнем случае вам поможет `Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString())`

Comment: Покажите код и продемонстрируйте на примерах, что вводится и какой нужен результат.

Comment: Читайте что пишется в сообщении об ошибке, а пишется там что переменная foodtotalint не инициализирована. Ещё судя по коду вы не очень понимаете что делаете, т.к делаете много лишних и бессмысленных действий и преобразований.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int foodtotalint = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }

    private void append(String foodstr) {
        foodtotalint += Integer.parseInt(foodstr);
    }
}
```

Всякий раз когда вам надо добавить число, введённое пользователем, вызывайте метод `append`, передавая туда строку, которую он ввёл. В итоге в переменной `foodtotalint` будет содержаться сумма всех чилел, которые вводил пользователь.